# SQL:Oracle - Cartesian product - in which case

Tags: sql, oracle, join, cartesian

Reading "Pro Oracle SQL" by Karen Morten, page 9 "FROM clause" says

> Joins are processed in the following order
>
> 1. Cross Join
> 2. Inner join
> 3. Outer join

So does Oracle always create a Cartesian product of the two tables involved in a join whether it is inner join or outer join?

Table A have values 1 to 10 (unique) and table B have values (2,4,6,8)

Inner join:

```
select a.a1, b.b1 from a,b where a.a1 = b.b1;
```

Outer join:

```
select a.a1, b.b1 from a,b where a.a1 = (+) b.b1;
```

Form a result based on

- Create a Cartesian product of 10*4 and then show records based on the criteria (outer or equi)
- Do not create a Cartesian product, just create a result set based on join predicate (equi join only not sure whether this can be done for outer join, I think Cartesian product approach suites for outer join)

Comment: asking for an explanation?

Comment: I think that quote is perhaps talking about what happens when there are *multiple* joins of different types *in the same statement*. I'm not sure it's right anyway though. [See the documentation for an explanation of how joins are processed](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/tgsql/joins.html#GUID-BD96F1B4-76D4-43DF-98B6-D07F46838C4A).

Comment: I would say that the statement "Joins are processed in the following order: 1,Cross Join 2,Inner join 3,Outer join" is incorrect; Oracle's optimizer determines the order in which tables should be joined according to what it thinks is best. That might be to process the cartesion/cross join last, first or somewhere in the middle.

Comment: If the book is explaining joins using comma syntax, then get another book.  You should be learning proper `JOIN` syntax -- it is more powerful and has been in the standard for decades.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - No it's not the syntax the author had used, it's me who find it difficult with JOIN syntax.

Comment: btw that should be `where a.a1 (+) = b.b1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't build a cartesian product of the two tables for a inner or outer join.

> The database uses a Cartesian join when one or more of the tables does not have any join conditions to any other tables in the statement." [Database SQL Tuning Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_join.htm#TGSQL94986)

So, in your example, it does a cartesian join only if the where clause is empty:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT a.a1, b.b1 FROM a,b;
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |      |    40 |   240 |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN|      |    40 |   240 |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | B    |     4 |    12 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   BUFFER SORT        |      |    10 |    30 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL | A    |    10 |    30 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    SELECT a.a1, b.b1 FROM a,b;
```

It normally uses one of three join methods, which are explained in the same [document](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_join.htm#TGSQL244).

In your case, it's using a "hash join" for the inner join:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT a.a1, b.b1 FROM a,b WHERE a.a1 = b.b1;
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     4 |    24 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN         |      |     4 |    24 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| B    |     4 |    12 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| A    |    10 |    30 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("A"."A1"="B"."B1")
```

and a "hash join outer" for your outer join:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT a.a1, b.b1 FROM a,b WHERE a.a1 = b.b1(+);
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |    10 |    60 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN OUTER   |      |    10 |    60 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| A    |    10 |    30 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| B    |     4 |    12 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("A"."A1"="B"."B1"(+))
```

Comment: Ok,For inner and outer joins it doesn't need a cartesian product. Got it.So for a full outer join, I thought it should be creating a cartesian product.
Reason, A Cartesian product can be used to match both left and right outer join conditions. My question is except for a case where there is no join condition,
under what conditions cartesian product will be used?

Comment: There is a technical difference between full outer join and cartesian join. Just checked it with a join of two tables with 3 million rows each: join 6.2 seconds for 2.8 million rows, full outer join: 7.4 seconds for 4.9 million rows. Cross join still running after a couple of minutes.

Comment: To your specific question, please check [When the Optimizer Considers Cartesian Joins](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_join.htm#TGSQL94986). Basically, it uses cartesian joins, 1) if you forget a where clause, 2) if you force it to or 3) if it is faster, for instance if you join two small tables to a big table, it might crossjoin both small tables.